# How to fill/change particular unknown strings of some sections of a well formated JSON file from bash keeping the format intact?

Tags: json, bash

How to fill/change particular **unknown** strings of **some sections** of a **well formated .json file** from bash **keeping the format intact** ?

Details:

Part of `settings.json` :

```json
     "profiles":
     {
         "defaults":
         {
             // Put settings here that you want to apply to all profiles.
         },
         "theme": "dark",
         "list":
         [
             {
                 // Make changes here to the powershell.exe profile.
                 "guid": "{61c54bbd-c2c6-5271-96e7-009a87ff44bf}",
                 "name": "Windows PowerShell",
                 "commandline": "powershell.exe",
                 "hidden": false,
                 "acrylicOpacity": 0.9,
                 "colorScheme" : "Material",
                 "cursorColor" : "#FFFFFD",
                 "useAcrylic" : true
             },
             {
                 // Make changes here to the cmd.exe profile.
                 "guid": "{0caa0dad-35be-5f56-a8ff-afceeeaa6101}",
                 "name": "Command Prompt",
                 "commandline": "cmd.exe",
                 "hidden": false,
                 "acrylicOpacity": 0.2,
                 "colorScheme" : "Frost",
                 "cursorColor" : "#000000",
                 "useAcrylic": true,
             },
     "schemes": [
         {
             "name" : "Frost",
             "background" : "#ffffff",
             "black" : "#3C5712",
             "blue" : "#17b2ff",
             "brightBlack" : "#749B36",
             "brightBlue" : "#27B2F6",
             "brightCyan" : "#13A8C0",
             "brightGreen" : "#89AF50",
             "brightPurple" : "#F2A20A",
             "brightRed" : "#F49B36",
             "brightWhite" : "#741274",
             "brightYellow" : "#991070",
             "cyan" : "#3C96A6",
             "foreground" : "#000000",
             "green" : "#6AAE08",
             "purple" : "#991070",
             "red" : "#8D0C0C",
             "white" : "#6E386E",
             "yellow" : "#991070"
         },
```

another file `pickcolor.txt`:

```
#FFFAFA
#FFFAFA
#EEE9E9
#FFC1C1
#EEB4B4
#CDC9C9
#F08080
#FF6A6A
#CD9B9B
#EE6363
#BC8F8F
#FF4040
#FF3030
#EE3B3B
#CD5C5C
#CD5555
#EE2C2C
#8B8989
#CD3333
#FF0000
#FF0000
#8B6969
#CD2626
#EE0000
#B22222
#A52A2A
#CD0000
#8B3A3A
#8B2323
```

Want to **create a bash which changes value of fields** like `"background"`, `"cursorColor"` **to any random value from**  `pickcolor.txt`

Requirements/problems I am facing:

1. Fields appearing many times gets different values from each other
2. Value of fields changes from time to time, so simple find and replace do not work
3. Fields changes there line number every time new contents are added, so line number for fields do not remain same.
4. Format of .json file should not change

Please note : I do not want anyone to write the complete code ; just hinting/pointing out ways will be sufficient. And thanks in advance !!

Comment: Sorry, what exactly do you need? Do you need to replace any color-like string with random colors from list? Or do you need to change values of fields with specific names with random colors from list?

Comment: @asm0dey  need to change values of fields with specific names with random colors from list

Comment: Then it looks like my answer should work for you. Please mark it as correct of it is or comment if it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you need is something like this

```sh
fields=(background cursorColor)
colors=("#FFFAFA" "#CDC9C9" "#EE3B3B")
size=${#colors[@]}

for f in "${fields[@]}"; do
    for line in $(grep -n "\"$f\"" myfile.json | cut -f1 -d:); do
        index=$(($RANDOM % $size))
        color="${colors[$index]}"
        sed -i $line's|\("'"$f"'"\s*:\s*"\).\+"|\1'"$color"'"|' myfile.json
    done
done
```

There is some magic in this solution:

1. We choose random index from array of colors
2. For each of fields which should be replaced we create it's own unique sed expression, which

   1. First part (`\("'"$f"'"\s*:\s*"\)#.\+"` finds anything matching pattern `"<field name>"<spaces>:<spaces>"<any color>"`
   2. Captures anything until 3rd double quote into group
   3. In second group (`\1'"${colors[$index]}"'"`) replaces matched part with itself, but inserts randomly picked color from array into second double quote group
3. Weird things with lots of quotes are made to interpolate field name and color into single quotes

NB: this is tested with GNU sed. May need a bit different syntax for BSD

Comment: Thanks for the help .It does replace colors as expected but i want same field to get different values if the field is occurs more than one time in the file.

Comment: @Madhubala please provide us with more information on how is your file orginzed. May we say that there is only one match per line?

Comment: sorry for unclarity . Will ask you to assume that the shared json file is completele. The code you provided above works as expected but only problem is that - for example 'cursorColor' for first time if set to red then second time it is set to any other value other than red. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Madhubala then solution remains the same but first you need to find numbers of all matching lines and perform replacement on each line.

Comment: @Madhubala could you check  please?

Comment: thanks for you efforts ; working as expected now ; accepted it as answer